# Replacing regular expression token with environment variable in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, environment-variables, template-engine

Having a bit of a fight with PowerShell. I'm trying to replace tokens in a text file with the values of environment variables. For example, suppose my input file looks like this:

```
Hello [ENV(USERNAME)], your computer name is [ENV(COMPUTERNAME)]
and runs [ENV(OS)]
```

I've tried the following:

```
Get-Content test.txt | ForEach {$_ -replace '\[ENV\((\w+)\)\]', "$env:$1" }
```

This gives the error:

```
At line:1 char:74
+ Get-Content test.txt | ForEach {$_ -replace '\[ENV\((\w+)\)\]', "$env:$1 ...
+                                                                  ~~~~~
Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReferenceWithDrive
```

I've also tried:

```
Get-Content test.txt | ForEach {$_ -replace '\[ENV\((\w+)\)\]', [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($1) }
```

But this fails to retrieve the variables and gives me this as output:

```
Hello , your computer is named
and runs
```

I've tried to call a function I defined myself, but get another error:

```
At D:\tfs\HIPv3\prod\Dev\Tools\EnvironmentResolve.ps1:13 char:72
+ Get-Content test.txt | ForEach {$_ -replace '\[ENV\((\w+)\)\]', GetEnvVa ...
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~~
Missing expression after ','.
At D:\tfs\HIPv3\prod\Dev\Tools\EnvironmentResolve.ps1:13 char:73
+ Get-Content test.txt | ForEach {$_ -replace '\[ENV\((\w+)\)\]', GetEnvVa ...
+                                                                 ~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'GetEnvVar' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

Anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this:

```
$string = 'Hello [ENV(USERNAME)], your computer name is [ENV(COMPUTERNAME)] and runs [ENV(OS)]'

$regex = '\[ENV\(([^)]+)\)]'

 [regex]::Matches($string,$regex) |
  foreach {
            $org = $_.groups[0].value
            $repl = iex ('$env:' + $_.groups[1].value)
            $string = $string.replace($org,$repl)
          }

 $string
```

Comment: Cool, this works! Any reason why the replace operator cannot be used?

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't use it, but for replacing literal values the string replace method is faster, and you have the literal values to use in the group values being returned by [regex]::matches().

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `[ENV(...)]` why not use `%...%` ?

```
$string = 'Hello %USERNAME%, your computer name is %COMPUTERNAME% and runs %OS%'
[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($string)
```

Which gives me:
Hello IanG, your computer name is 1EUKCOL1184 and runs Windows_NT

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"$env:$1"` (double quotes) use `'$env:$1'` (single quotes) and you should be OK. PowerShell will expand variables in a double quoted string. In your context `$1` is **not** a PowerShell variable: It's a regular expression token.

Comment: But that does not give the desired output. I need it to replace the tokens with the value of the environment variables. Your solution (which I tried before posting) gives this output: Hello $env:USERNAME, your computer is named $env:COMPUTERNAME
and runs the operating system: $env:OS